# Empty array inside custom defined function

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, nsmutablearray, nib

I have an NSMutableArray defined in my main class

```
    @interface EasyCustomTableController : UIViewController
    
    {
        UITableView *tableView;
        UIImageView *imageView;
        NSString *saveData;
        NSMutableArray *products;
    }

    @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *products;
    @property (nonatomic,retain)  IBOutlet NSString *saveData;
```

In the main .m all properties are synthesized and the products array is populated on **viewDidLoad**

My question is why is this array available in all methods (i used it to populate my table)

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

But empty at my custom function which is also in my main class

```
-(NSString *)saveData 

    NSLog(@"%d", [products count]);

    return @"Array is empty";
}
```

Thanks in advance

Mofi

Comment: `-[NSArray count]` does not return an `int`. The closest C type is `unsigned long`, for which the correct formatter is `%lu`. (`NSUInteger`, the actual type returned by `-count`, is defined as `unsigned long` on some architectures, and on the ones where it's defined as `unsigned int`, they're the same size.)

Answer (score 1):

Most probably, you have two instances of your class. Double check it by debugging and watching "self".

Comment: And the probable cause of this is instantiating your `EasyCustomTableController` both in a nib and in code, and *that* is most probably because the one you made in the nib should be the File's Owner of a nib instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot to both of you, I had indeed two declarations of the class. It is know working

Thanks